# Smallcaps in text and author index with biblatex 3.4 and biber 2.4

Tags: biblatex, biber

After updating my TeXLive 2015 recently, now including Biber 2.4 and Biblatex 3.4, I'm unable to get smallcaps for authors' names in text, footnotes and in the authors' index. When I revert to Biber 2.3 and Biblatex 3.2 (not sure if this was the version), I do get smallcaps where I want.

Here is my MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=name,intoc,title=Authors index]
\makeindex[name=topics,intoc,title=Topics index]
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Bibliography
\usepackage[backend=biber,%
indexing=cite,%
style=authortitle]%
{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{BOOK,
author = {Doe, John},
title = {great book},
date = {2015-04-01},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
\usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[name]}{%
\textsc{#1}}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}{\textsc}
\setlength\bibitemsep{0pt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Document
\begin{document}
This is text, with a slight\index[topics]{Complication}
complication.\autocite[33]{BOOK}

\printbibliography
\clearpage
\printindex[name]
\clearpage
\printindex[topics]
\end{document}
```

Here are the errors I get:

```
Latex Error: ./test_biblatex3_4.tex:27 Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@defformat@d.

Latex Error: ./test_biblatex3_4.tex:27 Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@defformat@d.

Latex Error: ./test_biblatex3_4.tex:27 Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@defformat@d.

Latex Error: ./test_biblatex3_4.tex:34 Illegal parameter number in definition of \theindexentry.

Latex Error: ./test_biblatex3_4.tex:34 Illegal parameter number in definition of \theindexentry.

Latex Error: ./test_biblatex3_4.tex:34 Illegal parameter number in definition of \theindexentry.

Latex Error: ./test_biblatex3_4.tex:34 Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.

Latex Error: ./test_biblatex3_4.tex:34 Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.

Latex Error: ./test_biblatex3_4.tex:34 Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The syntax of the macro has changed. You need to update your code to use the new syntax. There was a question about it earlier if you poke. Ulrike Fischer posted a reference to stuff about the change in the comments. Take a look.

Comment: @cfr: I did spend considerable time trying to find answers before I posted but couldn't and still can't locate the source for the new syntax.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299036/bibtex-custom-citing/299084#299084 http://www.texdev.net/2016/03/13/biblatex-a-new-syntax-for-declarenameformat/  https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/372 and naturally the documentation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for taking the time to explain the new format. I did have a look at the documentation but didn't understand it.

Comment: Here is the new format for styling I adopted for last names in index of authors: `\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
    \nameparts{#1}
    \usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[name]}
    {\textsc{\namepartfamily}}
    {\textsc{\namepartgiveni}}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%`