# Downgrade biblatex and biber (due to change to name formats in biblatex 3.3)

Tags: biblatex, miktex, biber

I use the `droit-fr` class but it doesn't work anymore after the [changes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299084/82783) made to name formats in biblatex 3.3. I'll contact the developer, but the update is not trivial.

In the meantime, what would be the best way to downgrade both biblatex (to v. 3.2) and biber (to v. 2.3) (I use MiKTeX 2.9) ? Can I merely copy-paste the relevant files (… !) from an old backup ?

Thanks !

Comment: Get a biblatex.tds.tgz from here. Unpack in somewhere outside miktex and attach the root folder as a new root in miktex settings. That makes it easy to remove it later: you can simply detach it. You can put the older biber.exe where ever you want in your path. You can also rename it to e.g. biberold.exe and change your editor to use biberold.exe. Sorry forgot the link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/?source=navbar

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I've (almost) followed your instructions and it works well. The only difference is that I've renamed the latest (2.4) "biber.exe" to "biber_new.exe" (to keep it) and put the older (2.3) biber.exe in "MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64". It's hackish (and, also, biber.exe 2.3 is 32-bits) and I don't think that's a good idea… but I don't know how to make my editor use biberold.exe in your solution. I use latexmk to compile my document.

Comment: The 32 vs 64 bit issue should make any difference on 64-bit platforms. The changes required in the style for 3.3+ are not that difficult in fact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use another biblatex/biber version than the official (older or newer) you can do it like this:

Get a `biblatex.tds.tgz` from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/?source=navbar.

Unpack the `tgz` somewhere outside miktex and attach the root folder as a new root in miktex settings. This will make it easy to remove it later: you can simply detach the root.

You can put the accompanying `biber.exe` whereever you want in your path. You can replace the original biber (but it is possible that miktex realizes the change and tries to "repair" biber at the next update).  Or you can use some other folder:  if windows searches for biber there first you can simply use `biber` as command in your editor, in other cases you will have to add the full path. You can also rename `biber.exe` to e.g. `biberold.exe` and change the settings in your editor to use `biberold.exe` – I e.g. have also a `biberdev.exe` to test the development version.