# BibLateX - basic customization

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Let's consider the MWE below

- I need the citations to truncate the authors' list to two followed by
  "et al", however, this setting doesn't work [based on [Bernard's
  answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325810/conflict-between-minbibnames-and-maxbibnames/325847#325847)].
- Moreover, I would like the citation to be automatically encapsulated
  by square brackets.
- Finally, is there a quick fix to change the ampersand "&" with "and"
  phrase within the references?
- ADDED: (for `style=ext-authoryear`) how can I abbreviate first and second names of the authors with the initials? Solution: (`giveninits=true` in `biblatex` options).

Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,style=apa,maxcitenames=2,mincitenames=2]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Nachbagauer2015,
author="Karin Nachbagauer and Stefan Oberpeilsteiner and Karim Sherif and Wolfgang Steiner",
title="The Use of the Adjoint Method for Solving Typical Optimization Problems in Multibody Dynamics",
journal="Journal of Computational and Nonlinear Dynamics",
year="2015",
volume="10",
number="6",
doi="10.1115/1.4028417",
url="https://doi.org/10.1115/1.4028417"
}

    @Article{Dopico2014,
author="Daniel Dopico and Yitao Zhu and Adrian Sandu and Corina Sandu",
title="Direct and Adjoint Sensitivity Analysis of Ordinary Differential Equation Multibody Formulations",
journal="Journal of Computational and Nonlinear Dynamics",
year="2014",
volume="10",
number="1",
doi="10.1115/1.4026492",
url="https://doi.org/10.1115/1.4026492"
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    Hallo world \\
    \cite{Nachbagauer2015}\\
    \cite{Dopico2014}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general I recommend not to use `biblatex-apa` if you want a bibliography or citation style different from APA style. `biblatex-apa` was specifically written to comply to APA style in all its glory and with all its gory details. It can be extremely complicated to get `biblatex-apa` to change its behaviour even if "it should be easy".

#### `(min|max)citenames`

`citestyle=authoryear,style=apa` is equivalent to `style=apa`. `biblatex-apa`, in particular its citation style, does not obey `(max|min)citenames` as explained in [APA style in biblatex with three authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/455658/35864) and elsewhere because the APA requires special behaviour when truncating authors. With

```
style=apa,citestyle=authoryear
```

(which is equivalent to `bibstyle=apa,citestyle=authoryear`) the citation style is `authoryear` and `(min|max)citenames` is honoured.

#### square brackets for citations

That is very easy with styles of my [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) bundle. Simply use

```
citestyle=ext-authoryear
```

instead of `citestyle=authoryear` and issue

```
\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}
```

then set `autocite=inline` and use `\autocite` as your go-to citation command.

#### Replace "&" with "and"

This suggests that you actually don't want `(bib)style=apa` at all. Maybe `style=authoryear` or `style=ext-authoryear` already gives you what you want. If you insist on `apa` you need

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
    {}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{liststop}>2}
       {\finalandcomma\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
       {\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
    {}
    {\finalandcomma\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}
```

In total with `apa` bibliography style

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa,citestyle=ext-authoryear,maxcitenames=2,mincitenames=2,autocite=inline]{biblatex}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
    {}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{liststop}>2}
       {\finalandcomma\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
       {\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
    {}
    {\finalandcomma\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Nachbagauer2015,
  author  = {Karin Nachbagauer and Stefan Oberpeilsteiner and Karim Sherif and Wolfgang Steiner},
  title   = {The Use of the Adjoint Method for Solving Typical Optimization Problems in Multibody Dynamics},
  journal = {Journal of Computational and Nonlinear Dynamics},
  year    = {2015},
  volume  = {10},
  number  = {6},
  doi     = {10.1115/1.4028417},
}

@article{Dopico2014,
  author  = {Daniel Dopico and Yitao Zhu and Adrian Sandu and Corina Sandu},
  title   = {Direct and Adjoint Sensitivity Analysis of Ordinary Differential Equation Multibody Formulations},
  journal = {Journal of Computational and Nonlinear Dynamics},
  year    = {2014},
  volume  = {10},
  number  = {1},
  doi     = {10.1115/1.4026492},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Lorem ipsum

  \autocite{Nachbagauer2015}

  \autocite{Dopico2014}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: APA bibliography]

or with `ext-authoryear` bibliography style

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear,
  maxbibnames=999, maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=2,
  giveninits=true, uniquename=init,
  articlein=false, innamebeforetitle=true,
  autocite=inline]{biblatex}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  Lorem ipsum

  \autocite{sigfridsson}

  \autocite{aksin}

  \autocite{companion}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: author-year bibliography]

Comment: Great, everything works fine! Thank you for help :) I came up with one more question and added it above (hope it's not a big deal).

Comment: Ok, the last question wasn't hard to find out. Cheers!