# Problems in compiling CV

Tags: miktex, installing

I am updating my CV, first time I do it with Latex, and I decided to use the template I downloaded from this link https://it.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/fancy-cv

I wrote my CV and I tried to compile it either with pdflatex and with pdftex but I got the same error

```
2017-03-03 21:03:36,514+0100 INFO  pdflatex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2017-03-03 21:04:19,006+0100 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2017-03-03 21:08:41,339+0100 FATAL pdflatex - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2017-03-03 21:08:41,339+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2017-03-03 21:08:41,339+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp
2017-03-03 21:08:41,339+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 45
2017-03-03 21:09:23,304+0100 FATAL pdflatex - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2017-03-03 21:09:23,304+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2017-03-03 21:09:23,304+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp
2017-03-03 21:09:23,304+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 45
```

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: It looks like a fairly common non-CTAN class (really a "template", I suppose) called "Friggeri". Unless it's been changed, you need to use either `xelatex` or `lualatex`, not `pdflatex` to compile it. But you are providing a link to a site that requires registration (which I don't feel up to at the moment), so I don't really know what you are doing. If you are compiling offline, why are you using ShareLaTeX? (Note that for *TeX-related issues, the code that produces the error is usually far more important than the error message the code produces.)

Comment: What I did was to download the template from the link I sent and modified it to fill with my informations. I just tried to compile it either with xelatex and lualatex but it did not work as well. Is there something else I can do?

Comment: That template is broken in so many ways. It won't compile on a current TeX installation even without any changes.

Comment: Generally speaking, I'd advise against using it even if it did work. Creating a CV is a great way to learn LaTeX (if you are not in a rush): it involves different things like page layouts, environments, lists, tables, font-changing, bibliography, etc. Since similar information is likely repeated, it also encourages you to think about how to move from *ad hoc* LaTeX programming to how to write effective macros in order to achieve consistency in formatting.  (I should also add that I do not have the file you refer to, so I can't advise how to 'fix' it.)

Answer (score 3):

Your issue might be because the `Biblatex` has changed certain commands, e.g., `\DeclareNameFormat`. More details can be found in [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299036/biblatex-3-3-name-formatting).
Based on it, I made several changes on the `friggeri-cv.cls` which I downloaded from the link your provided.

First of all, I added the following sentences (modified from the ones from [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299036/biblatex-3-3-name-formatting))

```
\newbibmacro{name:newformat}{%
\ifblank{\namepartgiven}{}{\namepartgiven\space}\namepartfamily%
%\textbf{\namepartfamily}  % #1->\namepartfamily, #2->\namepartfamilyi
%\textbf{\namepartgiven}   % #3->\namepartgiven,  #4->\namepartgiveni
%[prefix: \namepartprefix] % #5->\namepartprefix, #6->\namepartprefixi
%[suffix: \namepartsuffix] % #7->\namepartsuffix, #8->\namepartsuffixi
}
```

Just before the `\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%`, and then I changed the 
declare of the name format as follows.

```
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
\small\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}%
\nameparts{#1}% split the name data, will not be necessary in future versions
\usebibmacro{name:newformat}%
\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
{\addcomma\space}
{}%
}
```

Eventually, it works. But you should use `xelatex` to compile it. 
If you see all the links are surrounded by rectangles, then you can add
the following settings for `hyperref` in your `cv.tex`.

```
\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: See also [Updating Friggeri's CV - Making it work with texlive 2015 and up - Too many errors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327316/35864). But I'm not sure if that is the problem the OP is really facing. Note that your `name:newformat` is a very unusual way to get the name formatting right, it does not support name suffix and prefix.