# friggeri-cv Aside appears on second page and not on first page

Tags: friggeri-cv

friggeri-cv Aside appears on second page and not on first page.

```
    \documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

%------------
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=30mm]%[leftmargin=*,align=left,itemindent=-\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelindent+\labelsep\relax]
}{%
  \end{itemize}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\renewcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  \item[#1]
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }
  
  
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{frontColor}{rgb}{0.30,0.30,0.30}% darkgrey
\definecolor{backColor}{RGB}{200,200,200}% grey
\newcommand{\grade}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (1em-.4em,-.35em) rectangle (5em +.5em ,1em);
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,5}{
        \path[{fill=backColor}] (\x em,0) circle (.35em);
    }
    \begin{scope}
    \clip (1em-.4em,-.35em) rectangle (#1em +.5em ,1em);
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,5}{
        \path[{fill=frontColor}] (\x em,0) circle (.35em);
    }
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
  
  
  
  

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\header{Patrick}{} 
            {Junior web developer} % Your name and current job title/field

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SIDEBAR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\aside{
\subsubsection{persoonlijke gegevens}
\small Mo 24 \\
 H \\
België\vspace{1 mm} \\
Geboren te , \\
25 november\vspace{1 mm} \\
Ongehuwd\vspace{1 mm} \\
Rijbewijs B, \\
in bezit van eigen vervoer\vspace{1 mm} \\
+32 485  \faPhone{}\vspace{1 mm} \\
\href{mailto:patrick@gmail.com}{\footnotesize patrick@gmail.com} \faEnvelope{}\vspace{1 mm}  \\
\href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/patrick-xxxx-101/}{LinkedIn profile} \faLinkedin{}\vspace{1 mm} \\
\href{https://github.com/patricxxxxxx}{Github account} \faGithub{}\vspace{2 mm} \\
\subsubsection{talen}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{3.5mm}Nederlands:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{5}  \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{3.5mm}\hfill Engels:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{4.0}\\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{3.5mm}\hfill Frans:\hspace{1mm}  & \grade{3.5}  \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{3.5mm}\hfill Duits:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{0.5}
\vspace{4mm}
\end{tabular}
\subsubsection{vaardigheden}
Assertief \\
Analytisch \\
Collegialiteit \\
Commercieel inzicht \\
Leervermogen\vspace{1 mm}  \\
\subsubsection{\small programmeertalen}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill html5:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{4.5}  \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill ccs3:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{4.0} \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill sass:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{3.0}\\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill bootstrap:\hspace{1mm}  & \grade{3.5}  \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill javascript:\hspace{1mm}  & \grade{4.0}  \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill jquery:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{3.5} \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill php:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{4.5} \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill codeigniter:\hspace{1mm}  & \grade{2.5}  \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill symfony:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{4.0} \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill laravel:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{4.5} \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill latex:\hspace{1mm}  & \grade{1.5}  \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill git:\hspace{1mm}  & \grade{4.0}  \\
\vspace{1.5mm}
\end{tabular}
\subsubsection{webshops}
Wordpress (Woocommerce), 
Opencart\vspace{2 mm} 
\subsubsection{databases}
Mysql, 
MS-SQL\vspace{2 mm} 
\subsubsection{servers}
Ubuntu server \\
Windows server\vspace{2 mm} 
\subsubsection{office}
LibreOffice, 
MSOffice\vspace{2 mm} 
\subsubsection{\small datacommunicatie}
CCNA Module 1
}



\section{profiel}

{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{studies}

\begin{entrylist}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{05/2019--12/2019}
{Opleiding {\normalfont opleiding webdeveloper}}
{City}
{\emph{HTML5/CSS3/PHP/Symfony/Laravel}} \\

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{09/2014--06/2015}
{Opleiding {\normalfont opleiding webdeveloper}}
{Genk}
{\emph{HTML5/CSS3/PHP/Symfony/CodeIgniter} \\
Eindwerk:
\begin{itemize}
\item Een volledig werkende webshop ontwerpen.
\end{itemize}}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{10/2012--02/2013}
{Opleiding {\normalfont opleiding tot Cisco Certified Network Associate (CCNA)}}
{Geel}
{\emph{Succesvol module 1 afgelegd}} 

%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{04/2004--06/2005}
{Opleiding {\normalfont xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}}
{Aarschot}
{\emph{.NET-VB.NET/ASP.NET/MS-SQL/PERL/Gestructureerd testen} \\
Eindwerk:
\begin{itemize}
\item Een kassa programma voor een groentenwinkel.
\end{itemize}}



%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{06/2001--07/2002}
{Opleiding {\normalfont Vxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}}
{Hasselt}
{\emph{Opleiding tot pc technicus/netwerkbeheerder}}\\

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{09/1993--12/1999}
{Opleiding {\normalfont economie - moderne talen}}
{City}


%------------------------------------------------

\end{entrylist}





%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{werkervaring}

\subsection{voltijds}

\begin{entrylist}

\entry
{03/2021--heden}
{Employer}
{City}
{\emph{Webmaster} \\
Het onderhouden van de webshop voor.\\
Wordpress / Woocommerce\\
Synchronisatie met boekhouding software exact.\\
Grafisch banners ontwerpen in Gimp.\\
Deeltijds
}
%------------------------------------------------


%------------------------------------------------



\entry
{11/2019--06/2020}
{Employer}
{City}
{\emph{Full Stack developer} \\
Het creëren van webapps in Laravel en het maken van plugins in Wordpress/Woocommerce.
}
%------------------------------------------------

\clearpage
%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{01/2017--11/2018}
{Employer}
{City}
{\emph{IT Helpdesk} \\
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
}
%------------------------------------------------


\entry
{03/2016--08/2016}
{employer}
{city}
{\emph{Technieker} \\
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
}
%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{08/2015--03/2016}
{employer}
{city, Nederland}
{\emph{Junior Advisor} \\
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
}
%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{02/2009--02/2012}
{employer}
{city}
{\emph{Technieker} \\
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
}
%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{05/2007--02/2009}
{employer}
{city}
{\emph{Technische callagent} \\
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{06/2005--05/2007}
{employer}
{city}
{\emph{Programmeur} \\ Ontwikkeling van websites}
\begin{itemize}
\item OxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxT.
\item xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
\item xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
\end{itemize}


%------------------------------------------------


\entry
{11/2004--12/2004}
{employer}
{city}
{\emph{Programmeur} \\ Stage project}
\begin{itemize}
\item xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{itemize}

%------------------------------------------------


\entry
{09/2002--03/2004}
{employer}
{city}
{\emph{PC-Technieker/Netwerkbeheerder} \\
Hardware
}
%------------------------------------------------


\entry
{01/2000--08/2001}
{employer}
{city}
{\emph{PC-Technieker} \\
Hardware
}
%------------------------------------------------


\end{entrylist}




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{links}

\textbf{professioneel:} Mijn blog \href{http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.be}{www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.be} \newline\textbf{portfolio:} \href{http://www.patrick.com}{www.patrick.com} 

\section{interesses}
\textbf{persoonlijk:} computerliteratuur, tafeltennis, fietsen, wandelen
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the 'aside' bar only appears on the second page...

Friggeri-CV

```
\ProvidesClass{friggeri-cv}[2012/04/30 CV class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}%
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}


%%%%%%%%%%
% Colors %
%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{333333}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{999999}

\definecolor{green}{HTML}{C2E15F}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FDA333}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{D3A4F9}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{FB4485}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{6CE0F1}

\ifdefined\@cv@print
  \colorlet{green}{gray}
  \colorlet{orange}{gray}
  \colorlet{purple}{gray}
  \colorlet{brown}{gray}
  \colorlet{red}{gray}
  \colorlet{blue}{gray}
  \colorlet{fillheader}{white}
  \colorlet{header}{gray}
\else
  \colorlet{fillheader}{gray}
  \colorlet{header}{white}
\fi
\colorlet{textcolor}{gray}
\colorlet{headercolor}{gray}

%%%%%%%%%
% Fonts %
%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}

\newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{Roboto-Regular}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{Roboto-Thin.ttf}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Roboto-Medium}
\newfontfamily\positionfont[]{Roboto-LightItalic}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Roboto-Light}

%\setmathfont{XITS Math}

%%%%%%%%%%
% Header %
%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rolefont}{%
  \fontsize{14pt}{24pt}\selectfont%
  \positionfont%
  \color{white}%
}

\newcommand{\header}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=fillheader, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=4cm] (box) at (current page.north){};
    \node [anchor=center] (name) at (box) {%
      \fontsize{40pt}{72pt}\color{header}%
      {\thinfont #1 }~{\bodyfont #2}
    };
    \node [anchor=north] at (name.south) {%
      \fontsize{14pt}{24pt}\color{header}%
      \thinfont #3%
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{2.5cm}
  \vspace{-2\parskip}
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Structure %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{parskip}

\newcounter{colorCounter}
\def\@sectioncolor#1{%
  {%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        blue\or%
        red\or%
        orange\or%
        green\or%
        purple\or%
        brown\else%
        headercolor\fi%
    } #1%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
  %reset the counter once we exhaust all colours
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{colorCounter}}{6}}{
    \setcounter{colorCounter}{0}
  }{}
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
  {%
    \LARGE\headingfont\color{headercolor}%
    \@sectioncolor{ #1}%
  }
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
  \par\vspace{.5\parskip}%
  {\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} \@sectioncolor{ #1}}
  \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
}

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}[1]{
  \par\vspace{.5\parskip}%
  {\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} #1}
  \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
}

\pagestyle{empty}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% List environment %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{ifthen}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{2cm}l}%was ll
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[5]{%
  {#1}&\parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    {\positionfont{#4}}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{\\}
    {#5}\vspace{\parsep}%
  }
  }
  

\newcommand{\body}[1]{%
    &\parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
    {#1}
    \vspace{\parsep}
    \vspace{\parsep}
}\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Side block %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{everypage}

\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}

\xdef\asideHeight{5}

\newcommand\aside[1]{
    \AddThispageHook{
        \begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.5, \asideHeight) % {width}(xpos,ypos)
            \begin{flushright}
            \linespread{1}\selectfont
            #1
            \end{flushright}
        \end{textblock}
        %
        %all pages aside from the first should have the side bit further up
        %Crude hack to just redefine the y position as we go
        \xdef\asideHeight{2.1}
    }
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[style=verbose, maxnames=99, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{title}{#1\par}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{pages}%
    \newunit%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{note}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}%
    \printfield{booktitle}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{misc}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \printfield{booktitle}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{note}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{report}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \printfield{type}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

% biblatex name formatting changed with version 3.3.
% After this change the line "\ifblank{#3}{}{#3\space}#1%" gives an error.
% see also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327316/updating-friggeris-cv-making-it-work-with-texlive-2015-and-up-too-many-erro

%\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
%  \small\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}%
%  \ifblank{#3}{}{#3\space}#1%
%  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
%    {\addcomma\space}
%    {}%
%}

% Fix for biblatex 3.3
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
   \nameparts{#1}
   \small\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}%
   \ifblank{\namepartgiven}{}{\namepartgiven\space}#1%
   \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
     {\addcomma\space}
     {}%
}

\defbibheading{bibheading}[\bibname]{%
   \subsubsection*{#1}
   \markboth{#1}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\printbibsection}[2]{%
  \begin{refsection}%
    \newrefcontext[sorting=chronological]%
    \nocite{*}%
    \printbibliography[type={#1}, title={#2}, heading=subbibliography]%
  \end{refsection}
}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{chronological}{
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{year}}
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{month}}
}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Other tweaks %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\RequirePackage[left=6.1cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=false,
    citecolor=false,
    filecolor=false,
    urlcolor = false}

% A fix for \href{}{} colors not working with fontspec
\makeatletter
\def\HyColor@@@@UseColor#1\@nil{\addfontfeatures{Color=#1}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: If you use a non-standard class, which is not included in the normal tex distributions, you should always include a link to the class.

Comment: Like I've done now, adding the frigerri class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could redefine the `\aside` macro to use latex hooks instead of the `\AddThispageHook`:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

    \documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

%------------
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=30mm]%[leftmargin=*,align=left,itemindent=-\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelindent+\labelsep\relax]
}{%
  \end{itemize}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\renewcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  \item[#1]
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }
  
  
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{frontColor}{rgb}{0.30,0.30,0.30}% darkgrey
\definecolor{backColor}{RGB}{200,200,200}% grey
\newcommand{\grade}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (1em-.4em,-.35em) rectangle (5em +.5em ,1em);
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,5}{
        \path[{fill=backColor}] (\x em,0) circle (.35em);
    }
    \begin{scope}
    \clip (1em-.4em,-.35em) rectangle (#1em +.5em ,1em);
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,5}{
        \path[{fill=frontColor}] (\x em,0) circle (.35em);
    }
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
  
  
  \renewcommand\aside[1]{
    \AddToHookNext{shipout/before}{
          \begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.5, \asideHeight) % {width}(xpos,ypos)
              \begin{flushright}
              \linespread{1}\selectfont
              #1
              \end{flushright}
          \end{textblock}
          %
          %all pages aside from the first should have the side bit further up
          %Crude hack to just redefine the y position as we go
          \xdef\asideHeight{2.1}
      }
  }
  

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\header{Patrick}{} 
            {Junior web developer} % Your name and current job title/field

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SIDEBAR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\aside{
\subsubsection{persoonlijke gegevens}
\small Mo 24 \\
 H \\
België\vspace{1 mm} \\
Geboren te , \\
25 november\vspace{1 mm} \\
Ongehuwd\vspace{1 mm} \\
Rijbewijs B, \\
in bezit van eigen vervoer\vspace{1 mm} \\
+32 485  \faPhone{}\vspace{1 mm} \\
\href{mailto:patrick@gmail.com}{\footnotesize patrick@gmail.com} \faEnvelope{}\vspace{1 mm}  \\
\href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/patrick-xxxx-101/}{LinkedIn profile} \faLinkedin{}\vspace{1 mm} \\
\href{https://github.com/patricxxxxxx}{Github account} \faGithub{}\vspace{2 mm} \\
\subsubsection{talen}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{3.5mm}Nederlands:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{5}  \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{3.5mm}\hfill Engels:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{4.0}\\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{3.5mm}\hfill Frans:\hspace{1mm}  & \grade{3.5}  \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{3.5mm}\hfill Duits:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{0.5}
\vspace{4mm}
\end{tabular}
\subsubsection{vaardigheden}
Assertief \\
Analytisch \\
Collegialiteit \\
Commercieel inzicht \\
Leervermogen\vspace{1 mm}  \\
\subsubsection{\small programmeertalen}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill html5:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{4.5}  \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill ccs3:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{4.0} \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill sass:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{3.0}\\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill bootstrap:\hspace{1mm}  & \grade{3.5}  \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill javascript:\hspace{1mm}  & \grade{4.0}  \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill jquery:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{3.5} \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill php:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{4.5} \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill codeigniter:\hspace{1mm}  & \grade{2.5}  \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill symfony:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{4.0} \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill laravel:\hspace{1mm} & \grade{4.5} \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill latex:\hspace{1mm}  & \grade{1.5}  \\
\vspace{-2mm}
\hspace{4.0mm}\hfill git:\hspace{1mm}  & \grade{4.0}  \\
\vspace{1.5mm}
\end{tabular}
\subsubsection{webshops}
Wordpress (Woocommerce), 
Opencart\vspace{2 mm} 
\subsubsection{databases}
Mysql, 
MS-SQL\vspace{2 mm} 
\subsubsection{servers}
Ubuntu server \\
Windows server\vspace{2 mm} 
\subsubsection{office}
LibreOffice, 
MSOffice\vspace{2 mm} 
\subsubsection{\small datacommunicatie}
CCNA Module 1
}



\section{profiel}

{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{studies}

\begin{entrylist}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{05/2019--12/2019}
{Opleiding {\normalfont opleiding webdeveloper}}
{City}
{\emph{HTML5/CSS3/PHP/Symfony/Laravel}} \\

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{09/2014--06/2015}
{Opleiding {\normalfont opleiding webdeveloper}}
{Genk}
{\emph{HTML5/CSS3/PHP/Symfony/CodeIgniter} \\
Eindwerk:
\begin{itemize}
\item Een volledig werkende webshop ontwerpen.
\end{itemize}}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{10/2012--02/2013}
{Opleiding {\normalfont opleiding tot Cisco Certified Network Associate (CCNA)}}
{Geel}
{\emph{Succesvol module 1 afgelegd}} 

%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{04/2004--06/2005}
{Opleiding {\normalfont xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}}
{Aarschot}
{\emph{.NET-VB.NET/ASP.NET/MS-SQL/PERL/Gestructureerd testen} \\
Eindwerk:
\begin{itemize}
\item Een kassa programma voor een groentenwinkel.
\end{itemize}}



%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{06/2001--07/2002}
{Opleiding {\normalfont Vxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}}
{Hasselt}
{\emph{Opleiding tot pc technicus/netwerkbeheerder}}\\

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{09/1993--12/1999}
{Opleiding {\normalfont economie - moderne talen}}
{City}


%------------------------------------------------

\end{entrylist}





%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{werkervaring}

\subsection{voltijds}

\begin{entrylist}

\entry
{03/2021--heden}
{Employer}
{City}
{\emph{Webmaster} \\
Het onderhouden van de webshop voor.\\
Wordpress / Woocommerce\\
Synchronisatie met boekhouding software exact.\\
Grafisch banners ontwerpen in Gimp.\\
Deeltijds
}
%------------------------------------------------


%------------------------------------------------



\entry
{11/2019--06/2020}
{Employer}
{City}
{\emph{Full Stack developer} \\
Het creëren van webapps in Laravel en het maken van plugins in Wordpress/Woocommerce.
}
%------------------------------------------------

\clearpage
%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{01/2017--11/2018}
{Employer}
{City}
{\emph{IT Helpdesk} \\
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
}
%------------------------------------------------


\entry
{03/2016--08/2016}
{employer}
{city}
{\emph{Technieker} \\
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
}
%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{08/2015--03/2016}
{employer}
{city, Nederland}
{\emph{Junior Advisor} \\
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
}
%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{02/2009--02/2012}
{employer}
{city}
{\emph{Technieker} \\
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
}
%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{05/2007--02/2009}
{employer}
{city}
{\emph{Technische callagent} \\
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{06/2005--05/2007}
{employer}
{city}
{\emph{Programmeur} \\ Ontwikkeling van websites}
\begin{itemize}
\item OxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxT.
\item xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
\item xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
\end{itemize}


%------------------------------------------------


\entry
{11/2004--12/2004}
{employer}
{city}
{\emph{Programmeur} \\ Stage project}
\begin{itemize}
\item xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{itemize}

%------------------------------------------------


\entry
{09/2002--03/2004}
{employer}
{city}
{\emph{PC-Technieker/Netwerkbeheerder} \\
Hardware
}
%------------------------------------------------


\entry
{01/2000--08/2001}
{employer}
{city}
{\emph{PC-Technieker} \\
Hardware
}
%------------------------------------------------


\end{entrylist}




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{links}

\textbf{professioneel:} Mijn blog \href{http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.be}{www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.be} \newline\textbf{portfolio:} \href{http://www.patrick.com}{www.patrick.com} 

\section{interesses}
\textbf{persoonlijk:} computerliteratuur, tafeltennis, fietsen, wandelen
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Before I except your answer as solved, could you let 'aside' appear only on the first page?