# urldate=long does not work with nature.bbx style using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

In my bibliography, which is created using biblatex, I want to write the full date on which I have accessed the URL. For some reason only the year is shown, but not the full date. "urldate=long" is not working. Could you please help?

I have the following entry in my quellen.bib-file:

```
@Online{      MyOnline,
  Title       = {Title of Page},
  URL         = {http://www.somesite.com},
  URLDate     = {2016-06-15}
}
```

In my main.tex document I have:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,draft=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=nature,citestyle=nature]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
    sorting=none, 
    bibwarn=true,
    isbn=true,
    url=true,
    urldate=long,
    maxnames=20
}
\addbibresource{quellen.bib}
\begin{document}

\cite{MyOnline}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give us code we can compile to reproduce, using the standard `.bbx` if possible?

Comment: @cfr : I modified the question so that the code could can be run. I replaced the bbx to the standard bbx, as well.

Comment: It appears the option is not supported by the `nature` style. It works in the standard case.

Comment: Note that your `\DeclareNameFormat{default}` code is going to break with `biblatex` versions >= 3.3 (see [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864)). I suspect you could get close to what you want with `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{given-family}` and the `giveninits=true` option. Alternatively, the code should probably look like `\DeclareNameFormat{default}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiveni}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%}` (mod line breaks)

Comment: I'll update the style on CTAN shortly to address this: I think the option post-dates writing the style!

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the very helpful comment. I stumbled over this already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nature` style defines `@online` to only typeset the year, regardless of options. To get long dates in this entry type without changing the style, therefore, we need to redefine the relevant Biblatex 'driver' and replace Biblatex's standard formatting for the URL and date.

For example,

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,draft=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=nature,citestyle=nature,sorting=none,bibwarn=true,isbn=true,url=true,maxnames=20,urldate=long]{biblatex}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{% modified from biblatex-nature's bbx
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}% from Biblatex's standard.bbx
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\cite{MyOnline}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: long date for URL]

Comment: It's always tricky deciding what to do with things that the 'model' doesn't use: _Nature_ don't print the full date and I think one can argue things either way! That said, I'll probably look at this again.

Comment: @JosephWright Maybe you could set the `urldate` option to a format that only prints the year, so people can easily get out of that by overriding `urldate`; in that case you could use the standard `url+urldate` macro. ... But something would have to be done about using `year` instead of `urlyear` if the latter is not defined.

Comment: @cfr Thanks this is  exactly what I wanted. However, I moved this DeclareBibliographyDriver block in my own bbx instead of doing this in the main.tex document.

Comment: @anemal Just remember to incorporate any changes if the default one gets updated. (See JW's comment above ;).)