# Change Bibliography "Date accessed:dd.mm.yy" appearance

Tags: biblatex

I am using the `nature` citation style which unfortunately does not display the date on which I accessed a web page.

Thanks to this post:

[urldate=long does not work with nature.bbx style using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329250/urldate-long-does-not-work-with-nature-bbx-style-using-biblatex)

I inserted:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{% modified from biblatex-nature's bbx
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}% from Biblatex's standard.bbx
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
```

which allowed me to enable to print the date accessed like so:

> (May 30, 2020)

I would like to change to the look of it to something like Harvard style to make clear what this date means:

> (Accessed: 21 August 2017)
> [Accessed: 21.08.2017]

can someone help me and explain me how I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a current version of `biblatex-nature` (I checked v1.3c dated 2018/10/18) you won't need the `\DeclareBibliographyDriver` shown in the question: That code (or indeed a slightly better version of it) is already part of `nature.bbx`. `urldate=long,` is enough to show the `urldate` in full.

If you want to add text like 'accessed' to the `urldate`, you'll need to modify the `urldate` field format. You can base your code on the field definition from `biblatex.def`: `\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=nature,
  urldate=long]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  urlseen = {accessed},
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,ctan,markey}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: CTAN. The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network http://www.ctan.org (accessed: 1st Oct. 2006).]