# Errors for using "style=apa" with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, errors, apa-style

I am currently using `biblatex` version 3.4, Biber version 2.5, and `biblatex-apa` version 6.6, on a 2015 TeXLive distribution in Gentoo (x86-64).

I'm not sure what's happening, but just including the `biblatex` package (nothing else) causes a large stream of `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@defformat@d` errors.

For an example, let's take the following basic code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

Just a test

\end{document}
```

There's absolutely nothing else with the document, no special commands or altered settings, nothing other than just the basic lines, and the addition of `biblatex`.  No `.bi`b files (yet), no citations, and no bibliography list has been added.

As long as `style=apa` is there, it will spit out a long list of errors, such as:

```
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx
File: standard.bbx 2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count219
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count220
)
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@defformat@d.
<to be read again> 
3
l.368 ...ts{\usebibmacro{name:apa:last-first}{#1}{#3
                                              }{#4}{#5}{#7}?}}
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.
```

I can't use any other style, because the assignment I'm producing requires citations in APA format.  Am I doing something wrong?  Most of the searching I've done seem to result in questions relating to special circumstances, but as you can see, this is a vanilla document that just happens to have `biblatex` added to the usepackage list.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Do your versions match? There was a change in some internals between `biblatex` v3.3 and v3.4 and the styles all had to be updated.

Comment: Your versions of `biblatex` and `biblatex-apa` don't match. Try to update the packages.

Comment: Where do I find out what versions match with what?  The package numbers above are the highest versions of all those packages available on the distribution's package repositories.

Comment: To find out the package versions you are using, add `\listfiles` at the top of your `.tex` file, compile it and look at the log, you will find the version list between `*File list*` and `*******`.

Comment: Once you've got the packages sorted out, you also need to set the language mapping. See [problems using apa6e with biblatex-apa](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/36331). Also, a lot of these sorts of problems on Linux can be solved by not using the packaged versions of TeX Live but using a proper TeX Live install.  See [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092)

Comment: I can't exactly recall if the correct `biblatex-apa` version for `biblatex` made the cut-off for TeX live. It *could* be that TeX live 2015 (which is frozen) is left with incompatible versions of the two packages, in which case there is not a lot you can do. But it could also be that the repositories of your favourite Linux distribution are not entirely correct. You could install vanilla TeX live 2016 and everything should be fine (see Alan's link above).

Comment: Note that the [`biblatex-apa` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa.pdf) has the version requirements for newer version in the revision history. If you have version 3.4 of `biblatex`, you should have 6.9 of `biblatex-apa`.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I had to do some searching, but I found a copy of biblatex-apa version 6.9, and now things are actually working correctly.

Comment: Since it came up again, I thought we could re-open this and duplicate it to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361543/35864 so gentoo people can get more specific help.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864