# biblatex and `\ifblank{}`

Tags: biblatex

I want to change the output format of `\citeauthor{}` so that full names ("givenname familyname") instead of just family names are displayed. Therefore, I have to define a special format and change `\citeauthor` so that it uses this format for its output routine.

Like shown in the example in the `biblatex` manual (section 4.2.3, page 146; `biblatex` version 3.9), I use `\ifblank{\namepartgiven}` to check whether the current name has a non-empty field `namepartgiven`. The logic seems simple enough: If the test succeeds, `\namepartgiven\space` will be printed just before `\namepartfamily`; if the field is empty, `\namepartfamily` should be printed immediately, without any preceding `\space`. However, I wonder when `\ifblank` is supposed to trigger.

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@book{test,
  author = {John Doe and Smith},
  title = {How to write an extraordinary book},
  date = {2018}
}%    
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareNameFormat{citeauthor}{%
%  \iffieldundef{\namepartgiven}{}%
    {\ifblank{\namepartgiven}{}{\namepartgiven\space}}%
  \namepartfamily%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{\value{listcount}}%
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}-1}{\value{listcount}}%
      {\multinamedelim}%
      {\finalnamedelim}%
    }%
    {\ifmorenames{\usebibmacro{name:andothers}}{}}%
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printnames[citeauthor]{author}}%
  {}
  {\midsentence*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography

\citeauthor{test}\par\cite{test}
\end{document}
```

This code works as expected if `\namepartgiven` is not empty. However, the database contains no given name for the second author (Smith). Apparently, `\ifblank` doesn't trigger because the field is not present; consequently, it branches off to print the non-existent given name, followed by a space:

[image: Unset field <code>namepartgiven</code> does not trigger <code>\ifblank</code>, so additional space is inserted.]

So, how about checking first whether the field `namepartgiven` is used at all before checking whether it is empty? Just activate the first line after `\DeclareNameFormat{citeauthor}` and compile the document again! This is what you will see:

[image: Using <code>\iffieldundef{namepartgiven}</code> gives the right result when there are no given names -- however, if the field is set, the given names are not displayed.]

Not surprisingly, the erroneous space right before "Smith" has disappeared. But wait, what happened to John Doe? Why has "John" gone as well?

Does anybody know what is happening here? There must be something I haven't understood correctly -- or could this be a bug in `biblatex`?

Comment: `\ifblank{\namepartgiven}` never returns true.

Comment: You probably need `\ifdefvoid` instead of `\ifblank`. The example in the docs need tweaking. I'll have a look later, but maybe there is a simpler solution altogether.

Comment: What is the `{\midsentence*}` for? The standard is `\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}` so I assume you want `\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames[citeauthor]{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}`

Comment: (modulo line breaks and [zero-width chars](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7296/35864), of course).

Comment: @moewe (Sorry for the delay -- real life interfered!) Regarding the `\midsentence*`: I have one peculiar entry in my database where the name corresponds to `\namepartgiven \namepartfamilyi`; the author used his family name's initial as a pseudonym. `\citeauthor` will end with `\adddot` for this author, so I thought it would make sense to indicate that this is no end-of-sentence mark. If I understand you correctly, `\midsentence` will only be honored in the bibliography, not in such citations, and should be removed as redundant?

Comment: @moewe Regarding the wrong example code in the manual: Should I file a bug, or are you perchance the maintainer of `biblatex`? :-)

Comment: @Andreas I'm part of the 'team'. As I said in my answer, the manual has already been fixed: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/7f470c138fcb9e2312969d90f3bcc5e6e1841b9c

Comment: Mhhh. I would need to see the exact example, but normally `\adddot` is already an abbreviation dot and not a sentence-ending full stop, so `\midsentence` should not be needed, I would have thought.

Comment: @moewe Sorry, I must have missed this part. Thanks for the prompt fix!

Answer (score 5):

The standard styles use `\ifdefvoid` instead of `\ifblank`. The `\ifblank` in the docs is a remnant of the old name format scheme (see [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864)) when the names parts were not passed down as macros, but as arguments. The documentation was fixed in version 3.12 (commit [7f470c1](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/7f470c138fcb9e2312969d90f3bcc5e6e1841b9c)).

The answer to what you want to do is even easier

```
\DeclareNameAlias{citeauthor}{given-family}
```

[image]

Comment: OK,  the issue with  `\ifblank{}` not expanding its arguments is resolved. Now,  I have a further question: Why do the given names disappear if I enclose the `\ifdefvoid` in an `\iffieldundef` test? I know that this test is not necessary because `ifdefvoid` triggers on control sequences that are undefined, expand to `\relax`, or expand to an empty string -- so this is a purely academic question.

Comment: @Andreas `\namepartgiven` is not a field as such and so `\iffieldundef{\namepartgiven}` is always true (i.e. the 'field' is undefined). The only proper way to test `\namepart...`s is `\ifdefvoid`.

Answer (score 4):

`\ifblank` does no expansion on its argument, so `\ifblank{\namepartgive}` never returns true.

Expand `\namepartgiven` before `\ifblank` acts:

```
\DeclareNameFormat{citeauthor}{%
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\namepartgiven}{}{\namepartgiven\space}%
  \namepartfamily 
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{\value{listcount}}%
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}-1}{\value{listcount}}%
      {\multinamedelim}%
      {\finalnamedelim}%
    }%
    {\ifmorenames{\usebibmacro{name:andothers}}{}}%
}
```

[image]

If you're afraid that the argument to `\ifblank` needs more than one expansion step to deliver the final result, you can define

```
\newcommand{\ifblankx}[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\romannumeral-`Q#1}%
}
```

and use `\ifblankx{\namepartgiven}{<true>}{<false>}`. On the other hand, if you're confident that `\namepartgiven` just needs one expansion step, you can use

```
\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{<true>}{<false>}
```

Comment: The standard styles use `\ifdefvoid`.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! I never thought of checking the `etoolbox` manual for the definition of `\ifblank` because I assumed the official example would be correct. :-)

Comment: AFAIK the set up is such that we can always expect the `\namepart...` macros to need exactly one expansion step.