# References switching name and last names

Tags: biblatex

I'm having troubles creating my own references, as it gets desconfigured in the bibliography.

Here is how it have been done in the `references.bib` file:

```
@unpublished{apostila_cristiano,
    title={TRIZ},
    author={Ferreira, Cristiano V. and Forcellini, Fernando A.},
    year={2000},
    note={Apostila constituinte do estudo da Tese de Doutorado}

}
```

And here is my `main.tex` file

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

asdf
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

---

In the reference there are two autors, *Cristiano V. Ferreira* and *Fernando A. Forcellini*. What happens is, the bibliography is not ordering right the second authors name.

Instead of generating

```
Ferreira, Cristiano V e Forcellini, Fernando A  (2000). “TRIZ”. Apostila 
constituinte do estudo da Tese de Doutorado.
```

the copilation gives me:

```
Ferreira, Cristiano V e Fernando A Forcellini (2000). “TRIZ”. Apostila 
constituinte do estudo da Tese de Doutorado.
```

Could you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Virtually all formatting aspects of bibliographic entries -- including the decision whether to place the surname before or after the given name(s) -- are governed by the bibliography style that's in use. Please do share with us which bibliography style you're using at present.

Comment: Incidentally, you should supply dots after the abbreviated middle names, i.e., write the author field as `author={Ferreira, Cristiano V. and Forcellini, Fernando A.},`. BibTeX makes no assumptions as to whether the single uppercase letters `V` and `A` are abbreviations (of Victor and Albert, possibly) or complete given names that just happen to consist of a single letter...

Comment: A solution will depend on the bibliography package (`natbib`, `cite`, `jurabib`, `biblatex`, ...) you are using as well as on the style (the argument of `\bibliographystyle` for BibTeX-based styles or the value of the `style` option for `biblatex`). Please tell us how you produce your bibliography in an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: I've made the changes, thank you for the support

Comment: @Mico, I've tried adding the dot after the abbreviation and the result haven't altered

Comment: @Gilgamesh - Please note that I in no way claimed that adding the dots would change the sorting order of first and last names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` you can influence the order of the name parts:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@unpublished{apostila_cristiano,
    title={TRIZ},
    author={Ferreira, Cristiano V. and Forcellini, Fernando A.},
    year={2000},
    note={Apostila constituinte do estudo da Tese de Doutorado}

}
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

asdf
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change the name formats to the post-3.3 names (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864) to avoid warnings. Feel free to roll back the edit.

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot for your edit! I guess my biblatex/biber versions are too old to generate the warnings, but I'll wait for 3.12 until I update. (still using 3.10 at the moment)

Comment: No sorry, i was mistaken. The old `NameFormat`s do in fact not generate a warning. (Maybe we should look into warnings for version 3.12.) But they should of course still be replaced by the new names.

Comment: @moewe Warnings would probably be very helpful. The warnings made me replace `firstinits` by `giveninits`. I probably should have checked for other occurrences as in the `NameAlias` as well.

Comment: @moewe and I really like the warnings biblatex produces, because it usually exactly tells what to change :)

Comment: Well, then you are one of the select few that actually read the warnings ;-). I'll see what we can do. At the moment the old name is simply an alias for the new name. If we wanted to add deprecation warnings, we would have to either copy the entire definitions and add a warning, which does not sound very appealing to me. Or we could define a new command for aliasing with deprecation warning (my favoured option) but that would probably be a command no one ever uses (except the `biblatex` core for that one occasion).

Comment: See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/759

Comment: @moewe Wow! Very helpful -- thanks a lot!!!