# year vs date in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

This is a general (hope not too general) question concerning the (future) use of the `year` and the `date` fields in biblatex.

The short version of this question might actually be: "Is it likely that the `year` field will at some point be deprecated and should I switch to using `date`?"

But I'm actually curious about it more generally. The biblatex manual strongly encourages the use of the `date` field over the `year` field. However, I've been faring fairly well so far with using `year`. I rarely need month and day, or some of the other fancy stuff like eras and things, so for reasons of economy, I have found it easier so far to only use the `year` field and then for the occasional "in press," "forthcoming," or "no date" to use

```
Year = {\bibstring{inpress}}
```

for example, as opposed to leaving `Date` blank and giving

```
Pubstate = {inpress}
```

(since `date = {inpress}` or `date = {\bibstring{inpress}}` don't work). Having a `year` together with an `origdate` field also seems to be working fine (at least for `biblatex-chicago`'s author-date specification). So at this point I don't see a reason to change my database to `date`. 
However, is there any particular reason why I shouldn't use `year`?  Will it likely be deprecated in the future?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While `biblatex` has made its fair share of backwards incompatible changes (prime example: [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864), but I don't think there have been many incompatible changes w.r.t. the input in the `.bib` file) I think it is fair to assume that `year` will continue to be supported in `.bib` files for the foreseeable (and unforeseeable) future. Still **using `date` over `year` is encouraged** and it is a must if you want full dates with day precision or date ranges or negative years.

What I can not guarantee is that

```
year = {\bibstring{inpress}},
```

will continue to be supported. At the moment legacy `year` and the preferred `date` fields have to be treated separately in some definitions. That is a source of confusion and frustration for some and also a pain to maintain (cf. https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/714). Additionally sorting can be a pain and outright break if fields that are normally numeric in nature (years) come along with string values (https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/228).

**Arbitrary input in `year` could be problematic, I would only rely on numeric input being supported in the future.**

With a bit of tweaking (admittedly, for `biblatex-chicago` that might actually mean *a lot* of tweaking, you can of course contact the maintainer about this, I'm sure he will look into proper `pubstate` integration if he can find the time)

```
pubstate = {inpress},
```

should give you an output very similar to

```
year = {\bibstring{inpress}},
```

and it is also more semantically sound, and shorter because you don't have to type `\bibstring` all the time.

For the standard styles

```
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \field{urldate}
  \field{pubstate}
  \literal{nodate}
}
```

is enough to display the `pubstate` in citations. To mimic what `mergedate` does you could then also add

```
\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldequalstr{labeldatesource}{pubstate}
    {}
    {\printfield{pubstate}}}
```

to avoid duplication of the `pubstate` information.