# Formatting issues

Tags: babel, csquotes, biblatex-chicago, german

With the following code:

```latex
\RequirePackage[
    english,
    ngerman]{babel}

\RequirePackage[
    autostyle = true,
    babel,
    german = quotes]{csquotes}

\RequirePackage[
    authordate,
    bibencoding = auto,
    strict,
    backend = biber,
    natbib
]{biblatex-chicago}
\DeclareCaseLangs*{german}
\bibliography{./_assets/bibliography.bib}
\defbibheading{head}{\chapter{Literaturverzeichnis}}

\AtBeginBibliography{\def\UrlFont{\scriptsize\tt}}
```

how do I get rid of the first part here before `2000`?

[image: formatting issue]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a small compilable code reproducing the problem?

Comment: Hmmm, sometimes output like that shows if the name format in `biblatex` is not set up correctly or if some auxiliary files are corrupted. Unfortunately, it is not possible to reproduce the issue with the information shared so far in the question. We would need to see a so-called MWE that starts with `\documentclass` and has a `\begin{document}...\end{document}` environment (see also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: Make sure that your package versions are compatible by performing a *full* system update (if you are using MikTeX update in admin and user mode, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864). Then delete the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) and run the cycle LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX again. If the issue persists, please update the post with an MWE and include the `.log` file of the last LaTeX run as well as the `.blg` file (you can upload them to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/, https://0bin.net/, ... if they are too long for the question).

Comment: `\DeclareCaseLangs*{german}` looks quite dangerous. It enables `\MakeSentenceCase*` for use with German. Which means that German titles will be subjected to English sentence case rules: The very first character is capitalised all other words will be in lower case. That will seriously mess with mandatory capitalisation rules in German and is therefore to be avoided. With `\DeclareCaseLangs*{german}` `title = {Ein kurzer Titel},` will come out incorrectly as *Ein kurzer titel*.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit:

```latex
\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{
    \iffirstinits
    {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}
}
```

Comment: This is indeed outdated code for older `biblatex` versions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864. Note that this code could also produce spurious spaces because of unprotected line ends: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864