# Abbreviate author names as "Lastname AB" (without space or period) in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber

<strike>I want</strike> My journal wants author names to be abbreviated as "Lastname, FS" in the bibliography, but haven't found a way to do this after some excessive searching. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Here is MWE that shows how I don't want it to be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Lastname, First Second},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{key}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Since the question mentions a journal I should warn that I am not aware of a lot for journals that can accept `biblatex` submissions. `biblatex` imposes quite a different workflow on publishers than standard BibTeX or `thebibliography`, plus publishers are known to prefer stable (read: older) systems, where incompatibilities with modern `biblatex` could arise. Many journals have LaTeX templates and those almost never feature `biblatex` and usually insist on particular `.bst` styles or `thebibliography`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option `terseinits` does that for you. `terseinits` is a meta-option that essentially executes the following definitions

```
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitperiod}{}
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{}
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinithyphendelim}{}
```

and sets the test `\ifterseinits` (that test is not used by a lot of styles, apparently, so it hardly matters).

If you want a more fine-grained control, you can redefine these macros yourself. They do pretty much what their names suggest: `\bibinitperiod` is the punctuation after a name initial, `\bibinitdelim` the space between two name initials and `\bibinithyphendelim` replaces the two between hyphenated name parts such as `Jean-Jacques`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, giveninits=true, terseinits=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author    = {Lastname, First Second},
  year      = {2001},
  title     = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{key}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lastname, FS. Title. Publisher, 2001.]

Note that I changed the deprecated `last-first` to the new `family-given`, since you are already using the new name `giveninits` (cf. [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864)).

If you are using `authoryear`, you may want to redefine `sortname` and not only `author`:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}
```

Comment: The last period after "FS" is `nametitledelim`, i.e. the separator between the name and the title, and not a dot for the initials. If it should go as well, you may want to add `\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}`

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! I use `style=authoryear`, so the last period after "FS" doesn't show up, but it's nice to know anyway.