# Bibliography in Biblatex: Merging author's initials without a full stop

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I need to use in biblatex the provided in the print screen unfamiliar style for me. The journal that requires this style is Environment and Development Economics. It does not mention the name of this bibliography style.

I will be very grateful if you provide me with some help and/or a short sample in LaTeX on how to create a bibliography using this style.

I see that the key characteristics of this style are:

- Author's first and middle name (if available) are abbreviated to
  initials and merged without a comma after author's family name.
- If the author has two first names, their initials are hyphenated.
- Authors' names are in bold.
- Co-authors are introduced with "and" in all cases.
- Organisations are introduced with their full denominations.

The journal does not provide a LaTeX article template.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the name format you want to look into the `terseinits` option and the command `\revsdnamepunct` as well as the `family-given` name format. See also [Abbreviate author names as "Lastname AB" (without space or period) in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481852/35864), [biblatex: remove commas between last and first names in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17583/35864)

For the remaining features of the style, some more details are explained in [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864),
[Remove Quotation Marks from Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864), [Move names of editors followed by (Ed./Eds.) and a comma before title in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173638/35864), [Suppress "In:" biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864).

If you have any questions about the code below, just ask in the comments. Many names are pretty self explanatory.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  maxbibnames=999,
  giveninits=true, terseinits=true,
  uniquename=init,
  articlein=false,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}


\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{innametitledelim}{\newunitpunct}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodcal]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodcal]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodcal]{pages}{#1}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,nussbaum,geer,aksin,
  companion,westfahl:space}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Goossens M, Mittelbach F and Samarin A (1994) The LaTeX Companion. 1st ed. Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley. 528 pp.]

Please note that most publishers do *not* accept `biblatex` submissions. I would only look into using `biblatex` for journal submissions if the author guidelines explicitly mention `biblatex`. Double check what the submission guidelines have to say about LaTeX submissions and if there is an article template or document class.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Iva If the answer helped you, you may want to consider accepting it by clicking the green checkmark on the top left. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Done. I managed to replicate all journal's formatting requirements with your help. Again many thanks!