# Can´t get a comma after the title in Biblatex with IEEE style and online typ?

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style

I am writing my master thesis and started to work with biblatex. It is definitely easier than bibtex.
I discovered that there is a special online type for websites and I wanted to use it, because I use quite some websites.

I want to list the websites in the following style:

`Author, "Title", note, (date), URL, (URLdate)`

Because of this I use the IEEE style and change it when there is a dot, but I can´t get a comma after the author and after the website.

I only get the following:
[image: What I get]

Wich is

`Author. "Title". note, (date), URL, (URLdate)`

I tried to add the comma with the following, but this doesn´t work.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{tile}{\enquote{#1}\addcomma}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{author}{#1\addcomma}
```

Till now I used the type misc for websites, thats why i included it in my example code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{frage.bib}

\stdpunctuation
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{note}{#1\addcomma}
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{date}{(#1)\addcomma}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}


\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{tile}{\enquote{#1}\addcomma}%does not work
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{author}{#1\addcomma}%does not work

\begin{filecontents}{frage.bib}
@online{test,
author = {{Internationales Elektrotechnisches Wörterbuch}},
title = {{Definition Verriegelung}},
year = {2017},
url = {https://www2.dke.de/de/Online-Service/DKE-IEV/Seiten/IEV-Woerterbuch.aspx#},
urldate = {2020-09-23},
note = {IEV-Nr. 395 -07-120},
}
@misc{IEVVerriegelung,
author  = {{Internationales Elektrotechnisches Wörterbuch}},
title = {{Definition Verriegelung}},
date = 2017,
url = {https://www2.dke.de/de/Online-Service/DKE-IEV/Seiten/IEV-Woerterbuch.aspx#},
urldate = {2020-09-23},
note = {IEV-Nr. 395 -07-120},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite{test} \cite{IEVVerriegelung}
\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting question, first of there seems to be a typo: `title` not `tile`. Is it interesting that if one removes `[online]` then the changes does apply to `misc` but not `online`, why is `online` different

Comment: author is a name, so its format should be changed with `\DeclareNameFormat[online]{author}...`

Comment: @daleif thanks for hint about the typo, but this still doesn´t change anything and your right about about `misc`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for that, when i change it to `\DeclareNameFormat[online]{author}...` than i get `family=Internationales ElektrotechnischesWörterbuch, familyi=I.,`

which has probely something to do with [Biblatex 3-3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299036/biblatex-3-3-name-formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `xpatch` package to patch the bibliography driver for online entries. For use inside `biblatex` macros you should use `\mkbibquote` instead of the `csquotes` command `\enquote`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\addbibresource{frage.bib}

\stdpunctuation
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{date}{(#1)\addcomma}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}\addcomma}
\xpatchbibdriver{online}{\adddot}{\addcomma}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{online}{\adddot}{\addcomma}{}{}
\begin{filecontents}{frage.bib}
@online{test,
author = {{Internationales Elektrotechnisches Wörterbuch}},
title = {{Definition Verriegelung}},
year = {2017},
url = {https://www2.dke.de/de/Online-Service/DKE-IEV/Seiten/IEV-Woerterbuch.aspx#},
urldate = {2020-09-23},
note = {IEV-Nr. 395 -07-120},
}
@misc{IEVVerriegelung,
author  = {{Internationales Elektrotechnisches Wörterbuch}},
title = {{Definition Verriegelung}},
date = 2017,
url = {https://www2.dke.de/de/Online-Service/DKE-IEV/Seiten/IEV-Woerterbuch.aspx#},
urldate = {2020-09-23},
note = {IEV-Nr. 395 -07-120},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite{test} \cite{IEVVerriegelung}
\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks, that add the coma where I want it.  
I also want to change the dot after the note to comma.

I can do that with `\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{note}{#1\addcomma}`, is there also a way with `xpatch`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adjusting the field formats, it is easier and cleaner to change the driver:
(Some styles use commands for the punctuation which can be adapted, but yours not).

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}% <--- comma
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}% <--- comma
  \printlist{language}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printfield{version}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}% <-- comma ?
  \printlist{organization}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried it and now I have a comma after the author.

But I still have  no comma after the title. The result is the following

`Internationales Elektrotechnisches Wörterbuch, „Definition Verriegelung.“ IEV-Nr.
395 -07-120, (2017), Adresse: https://www2.dke.de/de/Online-Service/DKEIEV/
Seiten/IEV-Woerterbuch.aspx# (besucht am 23. 09. 2020)`

And with `\stdpunctuation` can change that to 
`Internationales Elektrotechnisches Wörterbuch, „Definition Verriegelung“. IEV..`