# Customize an apalike-german style with biblatex with a short-form documentation (German: Kurzbeleg) in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, german

I'm trying to customize an apalike-german style in Biblatex. The apalike style from BibTex was fine, but because it wasn't possible to change some small things (et al. instead of u.a) I changed to Biblatex.

I improved the Biblatex `style=authoryear` a lot, but it has still some problems. The `style=authoryear` doesn't have an short-form documentation in a bracket before the bibliography on the left.

That is the bracket on the left with author-year, that I want:
[image: apalike-german]

This are example references:

```
@misc{EuropaischeKommission.2011,
 author = {{Europ{\"a}ische Kommission}},
 year = {2011},
 title = {Was ist ein „Nanomaterial“? Europäische Kommission legt erstmals gemeinsame Definition vor},
 url = {https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/detail/de/IP_11_1202},
 urldate = {03/13/2021}
} 

@article{Siddique.2017,
 author = {Siddique, Abu Raihan Mohammad and Mahmud, Shohel and {van Heyst}, Bill},
 year = {2017},
 title = {A review of the state of the science on wearable thermoelectric power generators (TEGs) and their existing challenges},
 pages = {730--744},
 volume = {73},
 issn = {13640321},
 journal = {Renewable and Sustainable Energy Reviews},
 doi = {10.1016/j.rser.2017.01.177}
}

@article{Muller.2018,
 author = {M{\"u}ller, Eckhard and Stiewe, Christian and Ebling, Dirk},
 title = {Anwendungspotential thermoelektrischer Generatoren zur Abw{\"a}rmenutzung in station{\"a}ren Systemen},
 year = {2018},
 pages = {1--11},
 journal = {Gefahrstoffe-Reinhaltung der Luft}
}
```

That are the packages I'm using:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear-icomp, bibstyle=authoryear, sorting=nyt, hyperref=true, uniquename=false,
dashed=false, isbn=false, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=3, minnames=1 
]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{bib/references.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},}
\makeatletter
   \patchcmd{\blx@citeprint}
           {\blx@loopcode}
           {\blx@imc@bibhyperlink{#1}{\blx@loopcode}}
           {}{}
\makeatother
\setlength\bibitemsep{\medskipamount} 
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{{In:}\addspace\url{#1}}
\newcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\newcommand*{\bibfinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space} 
\AtBeginBibliography{
  \let\multinamedelim\bibmultinamedelim
  \let\finalnamedelim\bibfinalnamedelim
  }
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{EuropaischeKommission.2011} \autocite{Siddique.2017} \autocite{Muller.2018}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\end{document}
```

How can I change the biblatex-bibstyle to an `apalike-german`-bibstyle?

Comment: Well regarding the urldate: biber is warning you: `WARN - Entry 'EuropaischeKommission.2011' (test-apa.bib): Invalid format '3/13/2021' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring.`. Dates must be given in iso-format.

Comment: beside this: don't use the ngerman package, use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`, conference is not a known field, and volume should be an integer. I also wouldn't mix the apa-bibstyle with another citestyle. Simply use style=apa if you want apa.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want apa. I want an apalike style. Like the one bibtex had. The `citestyle=apa` has many problems, it uses for example `&` instead of `und`. With the `citestyle=authoryear` I'm satisfied, but the bibstyles `apa` and `authoryear` have many problems. So I thought maybe it's easier to customize the `apa` then the `authoryear` bibstyle.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I changed the date to a JJJJ-MM-TT format. Thanks, it works now :)

Comment: I absolutely cannot recommend combining `citestyle=authoryear, bibstyle=apa,`. `biblatex-apa` is only intended to give you APA style (7th ed.) output. It can be tricky to modify and customise and it is not guaranteed that mixing and matching this style with other styles (as in `citestyle=authoryear, bibstyle=apa,` instead of `style=apa,`) works without error.

Comment: @moewe ok, then I'lI use `style=authoryear`. So how can I make this style look like an apalike style?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "an apalike style". In a sense `authoryear` is already somewhat like APA, because it produces author-year citations. But obviously there are differences to both actual APA style and the `apalike.bst` BibTeX style. If you can ask about specific points you don't like about `authoryear` and explain what you would like to see instead, I'm sure you will get an answer here. (Just make sure to ask about each point separately.)

Comment: @moewe thanks, yes, I want an `apalike.bst` style. As you can see, I improved the sytle a bit. What I would like to improve now is an extra author-year in a bracket before the bibliography on the left and in the citations with three authors I'd like to have 2 authors + et al. (Now it gives out 2 + et al.)

Comment: Does that mean you want *exactly* the output `apalike` would give you? Is there are particular reason why you want exactly that output and still want to use `biblatex` instead of BibTeX, where you could just take `apalike`? It is most definitely not impossible to emulate `apalike` with `biblatex` to a very close degree, but that would involve quite some work, so you have to ask yourself if it is worth the effort. Questions that ask to implement a complete style are not a great fit for this site. It would be better to ask only about specific, but generally applicable things separately.

Comment: @moewe The problem with `bibTex` was, that it was not possible to change `u.a.` into `et al.`. So now I changed to `biblatex`, because here that's possible. It doesn't have to look like `apalike` exactly, but I want to have it similar. As you can see, I already impoved it a bit. What is missing now is not a lot. The biggest missing part is just the brackets on the left with `authoryear`.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. It is a bit late where I am, so I will go to bed soon, but I will have a look at this again tomorrow, if no one else answers it until then. I still don't quite understand which result you want. The question talks about `authoryear` being a mess (a bit harsh) and what it does not do, but it does not explain clearly and precisely what you want. If you want to you can include mockup screenshots of the output you want to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output shown in the screenshot with the citation label to the left of the entry in brackets comes from a misuse of the `apalike` bibliography style. That output is not the intended result. And indeed if you look round at bibliography and citation styles outside the LaTeX world very few (if any - I don't know any at the moment) author-year styles require that the citation label be repeated in the bibliography.

`\bibliographystyle{apalike}` should be used together with `\usepackage{apalike}` in the preamble. See the following note in `apalike.bst`

```
% This style should be used with the `apalike' LaTeX style (apalike.sty).
% \cite's come out like "(Jones, 1986)" in the text but there are no labels
% in the bibliography, and something like "(1986)" comes out immediately
% after the author.  Author (and editor) names appear as last name, comma,
% initials.  A `year' field is required for every entry, and so is either
% an author (or in some cases, an editor) field or a key field.
```

Hence,

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{elk}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

produces the incorrect

[image: [Elk, 1972] Elk, A. (1972). A Theory on Brontosauruses. Monthy & Co.]

output, whereas with `\usepackage{apalike}` in the preamble you would get the intended

[image: Elk, A. (1972). A Theory on Brontosauruses. Monthy & Co.]

`natbib` is largely backwards compatible with `apalike` (there are some edge cases with weird behaviour), so you can also get the correct output if you load `\usepackage{natbib}` instead. (Just don't load `\usepackage{apalike}` and `\usepackage{natbib}` together.)

Looking closer at the output in the screenshot you can see that the author-year info in the brackets is redundant. The author and year are clearly and prominently shown at the beginning of the entry in the bibliography anyway, so the author-year citation labels are easily matched to the entries in the bibliography even without the additional label.

---

If you insist on having the author-year citation label in the bibliography with `biblatex`, you can use [`biblatex-ext` styles](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext)<sup>Disclaimer: I'm the author</sup> and their `introcite` feature (see the [`biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf), pp. 15-21 in v0.13).

The "Example customisations for `introcite=plain`" on p. 19 come pretty close to what you want, but you can shop around for other options as well.

Here is how that could look in your document. Note that I simplified your `biblatex` options

- there is generally no need to choose separate `bibstyle` and `citestyle`: `citestyle=authoryear-icomp, bibstyle=authoryear,` is equivalent to `style=authoryear-icomp` (but we will use the `biblatex-ext` replacement anyway),
- the `authoryear` styles will automatically select `sorting=nyt,` so there is no point in specifying it manually,
- the setting `hyperref=true,` is usually no better than the default `hyperref=auto,`: Both options turn on links if and only if `\usepackage{hyperref}` is loaded. The only difference is that `hyperref=true,` will produce a warning if `\usepackage{hyperref}` is not loaded.

Some of your other code could be modernised as well: For context-sensitive delimiters like `multinamedelim` you should be using `\DeclareDelimFormat`. Then you can use the optional argument to change their behaviour only in the bibliography. No need for `\AtBeginBibliography` and `\bibmultinamedelim`. `\labelnamepunct` has been deprecated in favour of the context-sensitive `nametitledelim`. The name format `last-first` was renamed to `family-given` on v3.3 more than five years ago ([Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864)).

(I only removed the `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{{Zugriffsdatum:}\addspace\url{#1}}` line because I didn't understand its significance: clearly the `\url` is not the URL access date.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear-icomp,
  uniquename=false,
  maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=3, minnames=1,
  introcite=plain,
  dashed=false,
  isbn=false,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength\bibitemsep{\medskipamount}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bbx@introcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\UndeclareInnerCiteDelims{bbx@introcite}
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\quad}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [Sigfridsson und Ryde, 1998] Sigfridsson, Emma; Ryde, Ulf (1998): Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, S. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this substantial answer. Thanks also for `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` instead of `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. The `Zugriffsdatum` was a confusion of mine, I changed it to`In:`. Even if the combination of `\usepackage{apalike}` and `\usepackage{natbib}` was not the intended result, I Iiked it, it's very reader-friendly. I don't see it as an reptition, more as an indication.

Comment: Sadly `DeclareDelimAlias[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim} %missing}` gives me the error: `missing \begin{document}`.  ` \DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}` and `DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}` don’t change anything.

Comment: @Hanna You probably have an old system. Try updating or `\DeclareDelimAlias*[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I work with Overleaf, shouldn't it be upgraded by itself? One more question: Is it possible, to remove the comma between name and year in the short-form documentation (German: Kurzbeleg) in the reference list, so that ist looks like the short-form documentation in the citations?

Comment: @Hanna Overleaf don't update their system as often, because they want to make sure their users have a stable experience. For the comma remove the `\DeclareDelimFormat[bbx@introcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}`.