# Updating Bibliography modification for Biblatex 3.3+

Tags: biblatex

I would like to update some bibliography modifications I got with an older LaTeX template. I do know that there where some changes with BibLaTeX 3.3, but I seem to be missing something since latex still tells me "Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@defformat@d.". Maybe one of you can point me in the direction what has changed besides what's already mentioned in another thread.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[inreference]{title}{\bibstring{inrefstring}\addspace#1}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}   %Comma instead of Point
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{{#1}} %keine Anführungszeichen mehr
\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{
{\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}
\AtBeginBibliography{%Bold Authors in Literature
  \renewcommand*\mkbibnamegiven[1]{\bfseries{#1}}
  \renewcommand*\mkbibnamefamily[1]{\bfseries{#1}}
  \renewcommand*\mkbibnameprefix[1]{\bfseries{#1}}
  \renewcommand*\mkbibnameaffix[1]{\bfseries{#1}}
  \DeclareFieldFormat{year}{\bfseries{#1}}
  \DeclareFieldFormat{labelyear}{\bfseries{\mkbibemph{\mknumalph{#1}}}}
}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299036/biblatex-3-3-name-formatting

Comment: That's the thread I meant. But the only changes I saw there don't seem to be enough to satisfy the compiler. As you can see I already made these changes. The question is what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general advice for changes to pre-3.3 code is at [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864). The main idea is that you have to replace arguments (like `#1`) by macros (like `\namepartfamily`). Here, however, some things are easier.

---

```
\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{
{\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}
```

should be

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}
```

with a reasonably new `biblatex`. (Even pre-3.3 it would have better been written as `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}` instead of resorting to `\usebibmacro{name:...}`.)

---

```
\renewcommand*\mkbibnamegiven[1]{\bfseries{#1}}
\renewcommand*\mkbibnamefamily[1]{\bfseries{#1}}
\renewcommand*\mkbibnameprefix[1]{\bfseries{#1}}
\renewcommand*\mkbibnameaffix[1]{\bfseries{#1}}
```

can be simplified to

```
\renewcommand*\mkbibcompletename[1]{\mkbibbold{#1}}
```

Note that `\bfseries` is a switch that should be used as `{\bfseries <text>}`. When used as `\bfseries{<text>}` the bold leaks out. The macro form is `\textbf`, but its `biblatex` version is `\mkbibbold`. So again, this would have been bad style pre-3.3.

---

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelyear}{\bfseries{\mkbibemph{\mknumalph{#1}}}}
```

looks extremely suspicious: The year is generally not given in "alphabetic" form. Since `biblatex`'s `\mknumalph` cannot deal with numbers above 702, this will have never done what the name advertised. Plus, the `labelyear` format is not actually used, so this has no effect anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation. I have now made the suggested changes and it does compile without errors. For the labelyear part, I'm not sure what it's supposed to do. I just left it out. If somebody complains about the results, I can see what needs to be changed then and if necessary ask here again.